# find part of the word but replace whole word

Tags: javascript, sql, regex

```
str='world is the big sorrow'
f='or'
```

for example, i need to wrap with `<b>` all words from str, wich contains `f`:

```
result='<b>world</b> is the big <b>sorrow</b>'
```

i need fastest js or mysql solution in regexp

Comment: Have you even tried yourself. It's not that hard.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: most of them are like that, i just tasted something now...

Comment: ClasG, i done it procedural, but i need regexp sulution

Comment: Tip - prefix username with @, or no notification is made (just happened to see this).

Comment: @Tier I should post the answer if you show ur attempts.

Comment: @AvinashRaj He he... I thought s?he'd have to work a little as well... ;)

Answer (score 3):

OK - here's your regex.

```
\b\w*or\w*\b
```

It checks for a word boundary followed by 0 or more word-characters `A-Za-z0-9_`. Then your criteria - the `or`. Then again, optionally word characters up to the end of the word.

[See it work here](https://regex101.com/r/rV0aF9/1).

And the code thanks to Avinash:

```js
var str='world is the big sorrow';
var f='or';
alert(str.replace(RegExp("(\\b\\w*" + f + "\\w*\\b)", "g"), "<b>$1</b>"))
```

Next time, show us you've put some effort into it yourself ;)

Regards